# AJAX does not send FormData Correctly?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm working on something to send one image file and few data to PHP file. So I'm using a Form to do that. This is my JS code;

```
var pictureForm = new FormData();
var imgFile = $('#avatarSelect')[0];
pictureForm.append('email', email);
pictureForm.append('firName',editfirName);
pictureForm.append('lstName',editlstName);
pictureForm.append('newPass',editpass);
pictureForm.append('newPhn', editphnNum);
pictureForm.append('pictureFile', imgFile.files[0]);

$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "php/accountUpdate.php",
        dataType:'json',
        data:{pictureForm},
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success : function(response)
        {
            if(response==1)
            {
                alert("Success");

            }
            else
            {
                alert(response);

            }
        }
    });
```

And accountUpdate.php;

```
<?php
if($_POST)
{
$userEmail= $_POST['email'];
$userPass= $_POST['newPass'];
$userPhone = $_POST['newPhn'];
$userFName= $_POST['firName'];
$userLName = $_POST['lstName'];
$servername ="localhost";
$username="root";
$password="";
$dbname="AS2014459";

// Some code
}
else
 echo json_encode("Error");
?>
```

**My Problem**

However this always alert me "Error". Means $_POST isn't set properly. I couldn't find the reason. But all the variables such as email,editfirname...etc are properly set and have values.

Also when I run that on my local server (removing PHP if($_POST) condition ) console log says undefined index : email.  Any guesses?

Comment: are you using "enctype=multipart/form-data" for your form tag ?

Comment: @Santosh I don't have a form created in HTML. I use these data to create form in JS and send it via Ajax. So most probably I haven't set that in there. Can you please tell me how to set enctype in JS?

Comment: In the //some code section, what do you return as JSON?

Comment: @Adder I create a database connection and update database. Actually before I store file details such as name and location in database, I simply passed data using ajax (without form). That moment this worked perfectly. Problem occurred when I used formdata

Comment: @sam you can try this. next to your data in $.ajax call contentType: 'multipart/form-data',

Answer (score 0):

You haven't closed off the if/else statement therefore it echos out the error everytime and also use isset($_POST)

Comment: Which else statement?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the **1** with boolean value (**true**)

```
var pictureForm = new FormData();
var imgFile = $('#avatarSelect')[0];
pictureForm.append('email', email);
pictureForm.append('firName',editfirName);
pictureForm.append('lstName',editlstName);
pictureForm.append('newPass',editpass);
pictureForm.append('newPhn', editphnNum);
pictureForm.append('pictureFile', imgFile.files[0]);

$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "php/accountUpdate.php",
        dataType:'json',
        data:{pictureForm},
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success : function(response)
        {
            if(response==true)
            {
                alert("Success");

            }
            else
            {
                alert(response);

            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Can you be little bit more specific?

Comment: instead of **if (response == 1) {**
    **alert("success");**
**}** use **if (response == true) {**
    **alert("success");**
**}**

Comment: I simply return an integer value in PHP

Comment: the AJAX doesn't care what value is your response from the PHP file. response will be a variable of the AJAX not the PHP